# How to find a Cancer PPI network data

Tags: bioinformatics, cancer, protein-interaction

I need a Protein Protein Interactions network of Cancer (any type - just I want a PPI of any type cancer), I search and see DIP PPI and ....

How to specify that is  Cancer PPI and how to get a PPI of Cancer ?

Comment: What Cancer? What species? Please [edit] your question and make it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your are looking for human data. Take a look at these papers:

[Human Cancer Protein-Protein Interaction Network: A Structural Perspective](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000601)

From the abstract:

> Protein-protein interaction networks provide a global picture of cellular function and biological processes. Some proteins act as hub proteins, highly connected to others, whereas some others have few interactions. The dysfunction of some interactions causes many diseases, including cancer. Proteins interact through their interfaces. Therefore, studying the interface properties of cancer-related proteins will help explain their role in the interaction networks. Similar or overlapping binding sites should be used repeatedly in single interface hub proteins, making them promiscuous. Alternatively, multi-interface hub proteins make use of several distinct binding sites to bind to different partners. We propose a methodology to integrate protein interfaces into cancer interaction networks (ciSPIN, cancer structural protein interface network). The interactions in the human protein interaction network are replaced by interfaces, coming from either known or predicted complexes. We provide a detailed analysis of cancer related human protein-protein interfaces and the topological properties of the cancer network. The results reveal that cancer-related proteins have smaller, more planar, more charged and less hydrophobic binding sites than non-cancer proteins, which may indicate low affinity and high specificity of the cancer-related interactions. We also classified the genes in ciSPIN according to phenotypes. Within phenotypes, for breast cancer, colorectal cancer and leukemia, interface properties were found to be discriminating from non-cancer interfaces with an accuracy of 71%, 67%, 61%, respectively. In addition, cancer-related proteins tend to interact with their partners through distinct interfaces, corresponding mostly to multi-interface hubs, which comprise 56% of cancer-related proteins, and constituting the nodes with higher essentiality in the network (76%). We illustrate the interface related affinity properties of two cancer-related hub proteins: Erbb3, a multi interface, and Raf1, a single interface hub. The results reveal that affinity of interactions of the multi-interface hub tends to be higher than that of the single-interface hub. These findings might be important in obtaining new targets in cancer as well as finding the details of specific binding regions of putative cancer drug candidates.

[Tools for protein-protein interaction network analysis in cancer research](https://doi.org/10.1007/s12094-012-0755-9)

From the abstract:

> As cancer is a complex disease, the representation of a malignant cell as a protein-protein interaction network (PPIN) and its subsequent analysis can provide insight into the behaviour of cancer cells and lead to the discovery of new biomarkers. The aim of this review is to help life-science researchers without previous computer programming skills to extract meaningful biological information from such networks, taking advantage of easyto-use, public bioinformatics tools. It is structured in four parts: the first section describes the pipeline of consecutive steps from network construction to biological hypothesis generation. The second part provides a repository of public, user-friendly tools for network construction, visualisation and analysis. Two different and complementary approaches of network analysis are presented: the topological approach studies the network as a whole by means of structural graph theory, whereas the global approach divides the PPIN into sub-graphs, or modules. In section three, some concepts and tools regarding heterogeneous molecular data integration through a PPIN are described. Finally, the fourth part is an example of how to extract meaningful biological information from a colorectal cancer PPIN using some of the described tools.

Comment: Thanks, I looking for Cancer Data of Human or ... ! These are use Cancer data ?

Comment: Can you please expand your answer beyond dropping in some links? Some text about what is written in the articles would be great. Links tend to disappear sometimes which would make this answer useless.

Comment: @Digicom yes they focus on cancer data. Please take a look at [http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~natasha/course/docs/cytoscapeTutorial.pdf](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~natasha/course/docs/cytoscapeTutorial.pdf) to see a practical example of PPINs. Just follow the steps in the tasks and try to answer the questions. It will give you hands-on approach with what I suppose you are looking for.

Comment: @asalic Thank you. I will perform your tutorial and read your article.

Comment: @Chris All right, now the links won't disappear, unless DOI.org does. I cited the abstract from the papers, so any reader can now have an idea about the texts.

Comment: @Digicom You're welcome. Good luck and have fun.